# Деление файла на блоки С++. Отправка по блокам через сокет

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Делаю так

```
 char * buff = new char[a]; 
 b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in);
```

почему-то  b = 0

```
in = fopen(filename, "r");

int b; 
while(b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in))  
{
 send(client_socket,&buff[0],b,0);
 i++;
 printf("Отправляем %d блок файла \n", i);
}
```

Comment: А чему равно a? И ещё, файл in точно открылся нормально?

Comment: а = 512
вот для другогг файла сейчас нормально, b = 422 записалось,
только цикл бесконечный какой-то идет, вот код


     int i = 0;
     int b;
     int a = atol(buffer);
     char * buff = new char[a];
    // b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in);
    // b++;
    while(feof(in)) 
     {
  b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in);
  send(client_socket,&buff[0],b,0);
  i++;
     printf("Отправляем %d блок файла \n", i);
     }

Comment: а для текстового D:\data.txt  например b = 0 записывается
((

Comment: меня не будет в интернете до понедельника теперь(
если сама решу - будет круто,
но все равно - у кого какие-нибудь мысли будут как это исправить - напишите..

Comment: Я сильно огорчён, Вас будет сильно не хватать. Но -- счастливых выходных. 

Теперь. `while(feof(in))` или `while(!feof(in))`?(1). `D:\data.txt` как введено? Если как константа в программе, то сколько там обратных слешей (`\`)? (Это частая ошибка)

Comment: @АннаХатико, извините. Это я среди ночи немного ошибся (поэтому зацикливается). Вместо

    while(b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in))

надо написать

    while((b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in)) > 0)

или исправить код в Вашем последнем комментарии с

    while(feof(in))

на

    while(!feof(in))

Comment: с передачей файла разобралась)